# Running script at the end of cucumber test

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have a script I need to run after all my cucumber test. What's the best way to do this? It seems like the After hook only applies to scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the global hook `at_exit`:

```ruby
at_exit do
  your script goes here
end
```

For example, in features\support\env.rb I typically have:

```ruby
at_exit do
  browser.close
end
```